# Sequelize Mock doesn't work properly with Sequelize function "count"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sequelize.js

When I use Sequelize Mock between with a query like that:

```js
const {
    active,
    'in-progress': inProgress,
  } = await ImmediateCare.findAll({
    raw: true,
    attributes: ['status', [fn('count', col('id')), 'count']],
    group: ['ImmediateCare.status'],
  }).then((status) => {
    const counts = {
      active: 0,
      'in-progress': 0,
    }

    status.forEach((s) => {
      counts[s.status] = parseInt(s.count, 10)
    })

    return counts
  })
```

Is being returned `NaN`, I'm guessing that is because Sequelize Mock can't mock sequelize.fn('count')

Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was taking the wrong path

This is the test for the method.

I'm not supposed to test the Sequelize count response, I just need to mock the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) along with Sequelize Mock and stub the findAll call with mock data.
Something like this:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const SequelizeMock = require('sequelize-mock');
describe('', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
const dbConnection = new SequelizeMock();
const dbStub = sinon.stub(dbConnection, 'define');
const queryStub = sinon.stub().resolves(mockImmediateCareData);
dbStub.returns({ findAll : queryStub })
})
})
```

If this does not help, can you please share the defined mock object?
Also, the .`then()` is not needed as await is already being used.